# What caused my ANN to take drastically less time to run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, artificial-intelligence

I am currently working on an [open source ANN](https://github.com/Tysonzero/ANN) (for fun and as a learning experience) and I recently made what I thought was a relatively small change to my code, but for some reason it made the ANN run 16 times as fast. (According to my tests at least)

ANN/ANN5.py: (the old ANN)

```
from random import uniform


class Neuron(object):
    def __init__(self, parents=[]):
        self.parents = [{
            'neuron': parent,
            'weight': uniform(-1, 1),
            'slope': uniform(-1, 1),
        } for parent in parents]

    def calculate(self, increment=0):
        self.output = sum([parent['neuron'].output * (parent['weight'] + increment * parent['slope']) for parent in self.parents]) > 0

    def mutate(self, increment):
        for parent in self.parents:
            parent['weight'] += increment * parent['slope']
            parent['slope'] = uniform(-1, 1)

    def get_genome(self):
        return [parent['weight'] for parent in self.parents]

    def set_genome(self, value):
        for i, parent in enumerate(self.parents):
            parent['weight'] = value[i]

    genome = property(get_genome, set_genome)


class NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, hidden, rows):
        self.bias = Neuron()
        self.neurons = []
        for row in xrange(rows):
            if row == 0:
                self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=[]) for input_ in xrange(inputs)])
            elif row == rows - 1:
                self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[row - 1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
            else:
                self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[row - 1] + [self.bias]) for column in xrange(hidden)])
        self.bias.output = True

    def calculate(self, inputs, increment=0):
        for i, neuron_row in enumerate(self.neurons):
            for j, neuron in enumerate(neuron_row):
                if i == 0:
                    neuron.output = inputs[j]
                else:
                    neuron.calculate(increment=increment)
        return [neuron.output for neuron in self.neurons[-1]]

    def mutate(self, increment):
        for neuron_row in self.neurons:
            for neuron in neuron_row:
                neuron.mutate(increment=increment)

    def get_genome(self):
        genome = []
        for neuron_row in self.neurons[1:]:
            genome.append([neuron.genome for neuron in neuron_row])
        return genome

    def set_genome(self, value):
        for i, neuron_row in enumerate(self.neurons[1:]):
            for j, neuron in enumerate(neuron_row):
                neuron.genome = value[i][j]

    genome = property(get_genome, set_genome)
```

ANN/ANN.py: (the new ANN)

```
from random import uniform


class Neuron(object):
    def __init__(self, parents=[]):
        self.parents = [{
            'neuron': parent,
            'weight': uniform(-1, 1),
            'slope': uniform(-1, 1),
        } for parent in parents]

    def calculate(self, increment=0):
        self.output = sum([parent['neuron'].output * (parent['weight'] + increment * parent['slope']) for parent in self.parents]) > 0

    def mutate(self, increment):
        for parent in self.parents:
            parent['weight'] += increment * parent['slope']
            parent['slope'] = uniform(-1, 1)

    def get_genome(self):
        return [parent['weight'] for parent in self.parents]

    def set_genome(self, value):
        for i, parent in enumerate(self.parents):
            parent['weight'] = value[i]

    genome = property(get_genome, set_genome)


class NeuralNetwork(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs, hidden, rows):
        self.bias = Neuron()
        self.neurons = [[Neuron(parents=[]) for input_ in xrange(inputs)]]
        for row in xrange(rows - 2):
            self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
        self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
        self.bias.output = True

    def calculate(self, inputs, increment=0):
        for i, neuron_row in enumerate(self.neurons):
            for j, neuron in enumerate(neuron_row):
                if i == 0:
                    neuron.output = inputs[j]
                else:
                    neuron.calculate(increment=increment)
        return [neuron.output for neuron in self.neurons[-1]]

    def mutate(self, increment):
        for neuron_row in self.neurons:
            for neuron in neuron_row:
                neuron.mutate(increment=increment)

    def get_genome(self):
        genome = []
        for neuron_row in self.neurons[1:]:
            genome.append([neuron.genome for neuron in neuron_row])
        return genome

    def set_genome(self, value):
        for i, neuron_row in enumerate(self.neurons[1:]):
            for j, neuron in enumerate(neuron_row):
                neuron.genome = value[i][j]

    genome = property(get_genome, set_genome)
```

The diff going from ANN/ANN5.py to ANN/ANN.py:

```
-    self.neurons = []
-    for row in xrange(rows):
-        if row == 0:
-            self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=[]) for input_ in xrange(inputs)])
-        elif row == rows - 1:
-            self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[row - 1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
-        else:
-            self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[row - 1] + [self.bias]) for column in xrange(hidden)])
+    self.neurons = [[Neuron(parents=[]) for input_ in xrange(inputs)]]
+    for row in xrange(rows - 2):
+        self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
+    self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
```

(All within the NeuralNetwork's `__init__`)

tests.py:

```
from random import randint
from time import time

from ANN.ANN import NeuralNetwork
# from ANN.ANN2 import NeuralNetwork as NeuralNetwork2
# from ANN.ANN3 import NeuralNetwork as NeuralNetwork3
# from ANN.ANN4 import NeuralNetwork as NeuralNetwork4
from ANN.ANN5 import NeuralNetwork as NeuralNetwork5


def test(NeuralNetwork=NeuralNetwork):
    time_ = time()
    ANNs = []
    for i in xrange(10):
        ANNs.append(NeuralNetwork(inputs=49, outputs=3, hidden=49, rows=5))
    for i, ANN in enumerate(ANNs[:1]):
        for j in xrange(11):
            for k in xrange(len(ANNs) / 2):
                for l in xrange(20):
                    ANN.calculate([randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(49)], increment=j/10)
                    ANNs[k + len(ANNs)/2 * (i < len(ANNs)/2)].calculate([randint(0, 1) for _ in xrange(49)])
                    # print 'ANN {0} mutation {1:02d} opponent {2} turn {3:02d}'.format(i + 1, j + 1, k + 1, l + 1)
            ANN.mutate(increment=randint(1, 100))
    return time() - time_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'time: {0}'.format(test())
    # print 'time 2: {0}'.format(test(NeuralNetwork2))
    # print 'time 3: {0}'.format(test(NeuralNetwork3))
    # print 'time 4: {0}'.format(test(NeuralNetwork4))
    print 'time 5: {0}'.format(test(NeuralNetwork5))
```

I commented out ANN2, ANN3 and ANN4 because they are even older versions of the ANN that I store (locally only, none of them are on Github) in order to compare performance. Currently I am only worried about the performance change between ANN5.py and ANN.py

The reason why I did `for i, ANN in enumerate(ANNs[:1]):` instead of `for i, ANN in enumerate(ANNs):` was because the tests were taking too long with the latter, and I figured that the results would still be perfectly adequate without repeating the process for 10 ANN's (I occasionally do test with all 10 to make sure)

When I last ran tests.py this is what I get:

```
time: 0.454416036606
time 5: 8.02504611015
```

and it always gives something somewhat close to that.

I have done various tests comparing the functionality of ANN.py and ANN5.py and so far they have done exactly the same thing when in the same situation. I have used the genome property to make two identical ANN's, one that uses the NeuralNetwork class in ANN.py and one that uses the NeuralNetwork class in ANN5.py, and they always give me the same result provided the same inputs.

So my question is, what is going on? I realize that my question is not very precise but I honestly have no clue why there is such a huge performance difference. What I am hoping is that the old ANN (ANN5.py) is just doing something really inefficient in the background due to the way I initialized the ANN and that the new ANN (ANN.py) is initializing it correctly, but I worry that the new ANN has something totally missing that for some reason didn't show up / make any difference when I tested the two manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of forgot about this question and assumed something bad was happening before, but more recently I noticed that the genome being generated was fairly short. That is when I noticed that I was looping through xrange(outputs) which has length 3 instead of xrange(hidden) which has length 49.

After I changed:

```
for row in xrange(rows - 2):
    self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(outputs)])
```

To:

```
for row in xrange(rows - 2):
    self.neurons.append([Neuron(parents=self.neurons[-1] + [self.bias]) for output in xrange(hidden)])
```

It went back to similar speeds to the old code, but at least it generated an ANN of the correct size.